# How to exclude all subpages of parent ID form wp-list pages?

Tags: wordpress

I have sidebar with all pages listed using "wp_list_pages" but have issue with excluding.
If I add ID of page I want to exclude it will exclude only parent and firs level (children) but third level of subpages will be still displayed.

Thanks!!

```
wp_list_pages( 'exclude=2364,2366,2214,2368,2370,2372,2362,2836, 162,12101' );
```

Comment: Please follow this. It's same as per you want <br>
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26866/exclude-child-pages-args-array

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do it using:

wp_list_pages('exclude' => '2364,2366,2214,2368,2370,2372,2362,2836, 162,12101'));
```

Comment: Can use exclude_tree=5

That will exclude all sub pages of ID 5